# Make custom theme use null background (Android lint suggestion)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-lint

Im reading about the new Android Lint rules, and I find to prevent overdraw I should make my layouts with a background use a theme with null background, to prevent a background to be drawn if Im just gonna overwrite it. The problem is, how do I define a custom theme with null background?

Fail attempt 1 (doesn't compile):

```
<style name="NoTitleBarNoBackground" parent="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
        <item name="android:background">null</item>
</style>
```

Fail attempt 2 (warning persists):

```
<style name="NoTitleBarNoBackground" parent="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
        <item name="android:background">#00000000</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can try this:

```
<style name="CustomTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
    </style>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: recent studies have shown that you are a gentleman and a scholar

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What is windowContentOverlay item for?

Comment: Just to answer J.J.Kim - Setting windowContentOverlay to @null would override the value from Theme.Default. Thus removing the shadow from under the status bar.

Comment: This advice doesn't seem to hold anymore, in 2018. Don't understand why.